# Python's `dict` doesn't recognize its own key

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.6

**EDIT 2**: FINALLY I was able produce an MWE:

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar
T = TypeVar('T')

class Cache:
    __dict = {}

    @classmethod
    def add(cls, item):
        cls.__dict[item] = (item, [item, item, item, {item: item}])
        print('On setting:', item in cls.__dict)

    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        Cache.add(cls)


class Class(Cache, Generic[T]):
    pass

d = Cache._Cache__dict
tp = list(d)[0]
print('On checking:', tp in d)
```

In python 3.6 the output is:

```
On setting: True
On checking: False
```

While in 3.8 it is:

```
On setting: True
On checking: True
```

If that's not curious enough, if I remove the inheritance from `Generic[T]`, everything is AOK.

**ORIGINAL**

I'm using Python 3.6 and I get a `KeyError` when trying to get a key from a dictionary:

```py
# d: Dict[type, Any]

tp = list(d.keys())[0]
d[tp]
# KeyError: ...
```

Meaning that the very key taken from the dictionary causes this exception. Note that `d` has only one entry. The key-type is a type-object with `GenericMeta` as its metaclass, so might this be the issue?

I verified the following properties using the debugger:

1. `id(tp)` is the same in multiple calls.
2. `hash(tp)` is the same in multiple calls.
3. `tp is list(d.keys())[0]`
4. `tp == list(d.keys())[0]`
5. `len(d) == 1`

**EDIT:**

6. `print(type(tp))  # <class 'typing.GenericMeta'>`
7. `print(type(tp))  # <class 'dict'>`

My question is this: what might be the cause for this behavior?

I can't update the python version due to some of the packages' compatibility issues, so please don't tell me to update unless it's a known bug that's solved in a later version.

Comment: Please show an actual [mcve]. I have no idea what your code is actually doing, so until I do I'm forced to close your question as not reproducible

Comment: It's possible, though unlikely, that the person who wrote the key class is a joker, and did something like `def __eq__: return False`, although I would expect the `id` check to trump that.

Comment: I can't give an MWE because it doesn't reproduce in simpler cases. I'll keep trying to reproduce it. In any case, I don't ask "how to solve this", but "is that a known issue?"

Comment: It can't be the case because I checked this (see 4). Please read the question to its end.

Comment: It's not a known issue, and until you are able to track down where it's happening, it's going to be hard to help you.

Comment: Can't replicate. You need to do the work in narrowing down your actual code into a [mcve],

Comment: Alright. I can't post an answer because it'll be meaningless, but let's hash through the possibilities. What's `type(tp)` and `type(d)`?

Comment: Is `type(d).__getitem__` overridden by our hypothetical joker?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Edited the the verified "properties". All is normal.

Comment: is `tp in d` or `tp in d.keys()` returning `True`?

Comment: @Chris_Rands Returns `False`

Comment: @Chris_Rands `tp in list(d.keys())` returns `True`

Comment: Stop providing hints about what might be happing. Show an *actual* `dict` definition that we can recreate for which `d[list(d.keys())[0]]` raises a `KeyError`.

Comment: @chepner Had you read the previous comments, you would read that I can not provide an MWE

Comment: Yes, you can. Start with the real dict. Remove a key and check if it still produces the error. If it does, remove another key. If not, the key you just removed is the problem, and you can identify it.

Comment: @chepner Tried it. Doesn't work. It's actually quite curious!  `tp in dict(d))` is `False`, while `tp in dict(d.items())` is `True`.

Comment: I don't really understand why you can't provide a MWE, this really is needed to demonstrate this is *real*

Comment: @Chris_Rands I can't because I can't replicate it in a new environment, yet it is consistent between runs. This is very frustrating.

Comment: Even more frustrating is that I managed to run this in 3.8 after all and it doesn't reproduce there.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I was finally able to produce an MWE. Please reopen/vote to reopen the question (and remove any downvotes if you cast any).

Comment: @Chris_Rands Same goes for you

Comment: @chepner Same goes for you

Comment: @JohnColeman Same goes for you

Comment: Reproducible in Python 3.6, not in Python 3.7; my guess is it was a bug that got fixed. What that bug might have been is a mystery; I can confirm that `cls.__dict is Cache._Cache__dict` is true even in Python 3.6.

Comment: Good work making the mcve! This went from seeming nonsense to an interesting bit of historical python arcana

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an initialization order issue.

On Python 3.6, `Class` is an instance of [`typing.GenericMeta`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.0/Lib/typing.py#L884). `typing.GenericMeta` performs important initialization in `__new__`, but that initialization can only begin once `type.__new__` returns something to initialize. `type.__new__` is responsible for calling `__init_subclass__`, so your `__init_subclass__` runs before any `GenericMeta` initialization can happen.

When your `__init_subclass__` adds `Class` to the dict, initialization necessary for `==` and `hash` to work correctly has not yet been performed. This operation ends up using an invalid hash. Later, once initialization is complete, the lookup uses the correct hash and can't find `Class`.

On later Python versions, the whole generic class implementation was changed completely. `typing.GenericMeta` no longer exists.

Comment: Great. Thank you for your insight. Very interesting!
Anyway, that's roughly what I figured that happens. I guess that I'll either have to upgrade the runtime version or make the caching lazy (not on `__init_subclass__` but on first usage). Might cause overhead in multiprocessing, but might also be more efficient in the general case.

Comment: Anyway, so to sum it up - the hash value used to store the object is changed between insertion and extraction  (indeed a bug in python!). Also note the following interesting issue  that `dict(d)` (nor `set(d)` for that matter) does not recalculate the hash values of the inside objects (so it's generally more efficient than originally considered). To recalculate these values use `dict(d.items())`.